# Microwave transmission

Tags: transmission-line

I've just started learning microwave transmission in my engineering course.  The question that has been hovering over mind is "why do we need transmission lines (conductors) to transmit microwaves when we already know that microwaves can be transmitted wirelessly?"

I want to know like, what is the relation between these conductors and the EM wave (ie. microwave.)

Comment: How do you plan to get an antenna mounted on a box to the circuit inside?

Answer (score 1):

> why do we need transmission lines(conductors) to transmit microwaves when we already know that Microwaves can be transmitted wirelessly?

Why do we have coaxes connected to parabolic reflectors (LNBFs)? When transmitting, the coax and subsequently, the feedhorn, feeds the reflector with the intelligence (encoded, modulated, and power amplified signal) which is focussed onto the reflector by the feedhorn for transmission towards the target. So, a transmission line connects your transmitter module to the transmitting antenna, which is the final stage of the transmitter taken as a whole.

You are correct- microwaves are indeed thrown off and received by antennas (aerials). There are no physical media such as ethernet, coax or a fibre optic cable that is present in between the transmitter and receiver to carry the microwaves. Transmission lines are used to feed the antennas and there must be impedance matching between the transmission line and the antenna that it feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Microwave are very sensitive to geometry of conductors and dielectrics.

This geometry defines the  inductance, L and capacitance, C between and around the conductors.  The apparent impedance is sqrt of L/C = Z(f) and any mismatch will cause either reflective or conductive losses.

The EM wave is on both the conductors and dielectric including the air.  The air free space impedance is similarity defined by $$Z_o=\sqrt{\dfrac{\mu}{\epsilon}}$$

But you must study more how the EM orthogonal conventions are defined by Fleming’s Rules and complex shapes of fields with complex geometry such as stripline, microstrip and antenna theory.  Falstad.com also has simulations for 2D &3D force fields.

Answer (score 0):

> why do we need transmission lines( conductors) to transmit microwaves when we already know that Microwaves can be transmitted wirelessly?

Microwaves can be transmitted through
a) a transmission line
b) a waveguide
c) free space

Microwaves *are* transmitted regularly through free space, and this method is the most widely used when distances are great. The attenuation of microwaves through free space is small in comparison with the other methods. But confining the waves so that they reach receivers efficiently can be costly. Masers can produce very narrow beams, but are costly and bulky. Parabolic dishes produce beams that are directional, but wider than masers. The larger the parabolic dish, the more narrow the beam. Again, cost and bulk. The alternative, having a wide beam, is energetically inefficient.

Microwaves are also transmitted in wave-guides. Waveguides have a low-frequency cut-off based upon their cross-sectional dimensions. The lower the frequency the larger the waveguide needs to be. If the distance to transmit is short enough, waveguides are often the best choice. The big advantage of waveguides over transmission through free space is that the wave is "guided". Not only are the microwaves "contained", as if in a narrow beam, but the waveguide need not be straight. The drawbacks of waveguides are a) they have greater attenuation than free space, b) they require copper or other conductive material between the source and destination, which may get expensive for long distances c) they don't interface very well with common electronic components.

That brings up microwave transmission over transmission lines. Transmission lines consist of two conductors separated by an insulator/dielectric. Transmission line technology is typically used to connect electronic components, operating at microwave frequencies, at lower powers, and fairly short distances, such as across a circuit board. The advantages of transmissions lines include easy interfacing with electronic components, guided path between source and destination, no lower frequency limit, and low-cost for the applications where they are used. The major disadvantage of transmission lines at microwave frequencies is their high attenuation. Transmitting microwaves over long distances through transmission lines is simply not feasible for that reason.